# Enter data in / update cell by button only

Tags: vba, excel, button

I'm looking for a way to enter data in a cell only by the click of a button. In other words, I do not want the user to be able to update the cell by typing anything in it, he/she must click the button in order to update the cell.

I'm doing this to manage my employees' time sheets, and I want to avoid any possible tampering or forgery.

I have already created the button I want, and the macro associated with it is below:

```
Sub MyTimeStamp()
Dim DT
'
' MyTimeStamp Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'

DT = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
ActiveCell.Value = DT

End Sub
```

Is there any way of doing what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use data validation. This restricts what the user can put in the cell but not what VBA can put in the cell. In the cell you want to protect, select the cell and the invoke `data validation` on the data tab. Restrict it so that e.g. the user can only put a randomly chosen number that they are unlikely to ever try to enter:

[image]

make sure that you deselect `ignore blanks`. Choose appropriate input and error messages. If the user tries to bypass the button something like this happens:

[image]

As proof of concept I created a button with the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("A1").Value = InputBox("Please enter a value")
End Sub
```

A simple experiment shows that the VBA bypasses the data validation completely. For example, I just typed "this works" into the inputbox when I clicked the button and saw this:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I kept the _Ignore Blanks_ checked, so that the user can delete data if they entered data in the wrong cell.

Do you know of any way I can lock a cell (or a row of cells) based on the date? So in the weekly time sheet I have, the first column has the date, and I want only the corresponding row (Time in, Time out, etc.) for the specific day to be unlocked, while the other days are locked.

Comment: @FredGonsalves Yes, my idea of using data validation (which I like because of the pop-up message when you enter a cell) can be combined with Anthony Sherratt's idea of worksheet protection. You can unlock specific cells in a protected worksheet (but still have data validation for them) and then, perhaps in the Workbook open event, change which cells are locked and which are unlocked based on the date. The following tutorial might get you started: http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/excel-vba-range-lockunlock-specific-cells/

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to protect the sheet, locking down the cells. You can mark any cells you still want to be editable after its protected.

```
ActiveSheet.Protect
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
```

Use VBA events to unprotect/protect the sheet using the above commands. Move to the required cell and re-protect after they've entered their figure/leave the required cell.